# Passing iterators to a function

Tags: c++

I want to pass iterator of a vector of pointers to a function. I am not sure how to pass it.

Is this the right way of doing it:

```
main() {
    vector<MyObject*>::iterator it;

    for (it = added.begin(); it < added.end(); it++) {    
    string value = DoSomething(it)    
    }  
}
    string DoSomething(MyObject* a)
    {    
    if (a->isValid())
        Str = "0";
    ..
    ..   
    return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
string value = DoSomething(it)
```

should be:

```
string value = DoSomething(*it);
```

Comment: (Because `it` is a `vector<MyObject*>::iterator`, and `*it` is a `MyObject*`.)

Comment: Worth pointing out that this isn't the answer to the question that AJ asked, just the answer to the question he meant to ask. Probably.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to pass iterator of a vector of pointers to a function.

```
string value = DoSomething(it);
```

You're trying to pass it correctly, but the function isn't written to use an iterator:

```
string DoSomething(MyObject* a)
```

This function wants a pointer... you can give it that:

```
string value = DoSomething(*it);
```

Or you can change your DoSomething function:

```
string DoSomething(vector<MyObject*>::iterator i)
{
     if ((*i)->isvalid())
         ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to pass the iterator to the function, its parameter should also be an iterator:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string DoSomething(vector<string*>::iterator a) {
    string* entry = *a;
    cout << *entry << endl;
    return "blah";
}

int main() {
    vector<string*> added;
    string v1 = "v1";
    string v2 = "v2";

    added.push_back(&v1);
    added.push_back(&v2);

    vector<string*>::iterator it;

    for (it = added.begin(); it < added.end(); it++) {    
        string value = DoSomething(it);
    }  
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/1EzZlO).